# How to include the "Excluded" folders in search in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In Webstorm (I am using latest 2016.1 version), I have marked certain folders as Excluded since I dont want them indexed or files from them to show up as suggestions. But sometimes I do need to search for something globally including inside the excluded folders. How do I include every folder (even excluded ones) in my search?

I tried making a custom Scope, but in the scope-editor window, the excluded folders arent even showing up so I cant even select them. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Directory' scope in `Find in path` dialog: if the excluded directory is explicitly chosen there, it's possible to search in it

Comment: It works, but if I have multiple excluded folders, then I have to search in each of them manually one by one, which gets tiring really quickly. Hope IntelliJ would listen and add some sort of option to include the excluded.